# How to test a computer real general performance within C/C++ in a cross platform manner?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance-testing

I want a way to test a **computers real "overall" performance** within C++ in a cross platform manner.

I'm consider to run some simple tests whose is often used in benchmark suites software, but all benchmark (software) suites as I have found are either closed source or not cross platform. Therefore am I asking for advice/guidance, which algorithms are preferred? Are there any already free standalone libraries out there which I already can use without much job? Any help are appreciate.

I am consider to test:

- CPU/Memory speed
- Video-card speed
- Disk speed
- Parallel execution speed

I have been thinking if it is a **good idea to just copy Google V8 benchmark JavaScript tests** and run them in my already embedded JavaScript V8 engine:
http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/data/benchmarks/v3/run.html

I have some thoughts to do some simple disk copying,  data compression/decompression, factorial primes. For video card performance could I simple use SFML/OpenGL and do some GPU intensive things. But doing all those things should take some time for me, and it may not even be a good thing to do from the beginning, therefore the question:

**How to test a computer real general performance within C/C++ in a cross platform manner?**

If you got tips on good algorithms which I may want to use, please let me know, it could only help.

Thanks in advance!

N.B
I could check available hardware, but I believe the best way is to actually measure computer performance is to test it.

Comment: You list 4 things, that could be 4 separate questions. I'm sure there's plenty of people that can answer maybe one or two of those (like me). But all 4?

Comment: Sorry if I wrote to much, but I only want to test general computer performance, and before I starting to write my own benchmark code I thought it could be a good start to ask here first. The general question is still "How to test a computer real general performance". Any those side questions are only side-questions, to help you know what I am thinking.

Comment: Ah ic. Then it's kind of a broad question. The performance of a benchmark is only relevant if it's representative of what the machine is tasked to do. So it's hard to provide a "general" performance number.

Comment: Well, actually it will help me (together with some other information) decide if a computer have those performance requirements to run a specific program (all kind of) without performance issues. I just want to know a general way, it don´t need to be perfect (none is), just give me a indication how good a computer is, like CPU clock speed does when it comes to CPU performance. When does I at least have something to work with. PS. I know it is hard, therefore I am asking for help/guidence ;-)

Comment: I question whether there is such a thing as "general computer performance".  As your list indicates, all you can really test for is particular features (e.g. video-card speed) and even then you'll have to make assumptions about how those features are likely to be used in real life (e.g. is 2D or 3D performance more important?  At high resolutions or low resolutions?  etc)

Comment: I think you should search a little more for benchmark sources; for example the STREAM benchmark code seems to be available at http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/FTP/Code/

Comment: Jeremy Friesner:
I know which kind of software this score will be used for, which I will take into account, so those assumptions will be better than only using a raw "average benchmark score".
High Performance Mark: Thanks! It seems then I am not as good as you to find those resources then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"Real general performance" is best tested by running actual applications on the computer and measuring their performance. That's why 3D benchmarks include "real" 3D scenes that resemble "real" games as much as possible. The same goes with memory and CPU speed --- the most important thing is how a real memory- and CPU-intensive application runs on the computer. It's quite hard to mimic the operational fingerprint of a suite of real multimillion line applications with a small program.

I would rather collect some (open-source) real programs and find a way to run them automatically to assess performance. For example, take the GNU C compiler and run it to compile a big application; take any open-source accelerated 3D game (yes, they exist) and maybe patch it so that it runs for a specific number of frames, etc. For hard disk speed, take an open-source full-text indexing tool that builds an index on the hard disk directly, or an open-source database and perform lots of inserts and deletes etc. Then build a portfolio of tests based on real applications and then build a performance index out of those.

Comment: I believe I will go for it, but before I accept your answer. Can you just give some examples of such applications? Specially those C/C++ applications which I can compile easily (most be cross platform) and yet is not to large or too time consuming to compile, so I don´t need to stop the compilation after some time if the computer happens to be very slow. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean applications to run as benchmarks or applications to compile on GNU C as a compiler benchmark?

Comment: The later one, compile as a compiler benchmark (which only exist of few files with minimum dependencies). However if you know any good suggestions on whose programs to run as benchmark as whole, it should be appreciate if you tell them. Thanks!